# Calculate average pixel intensity for each frame of tif movie

Tags: python, video, pixel, tiff, scikit-image

I imported a `tif` movie into python which has the dimensions `(150,512,512)`. I would like to calculate the mean pixel intensity for each of the 150 frames and then plot it over time. I could figure out how to calculate the mean intensity over the whole stack (see below), but I am struggling to calculate it for each frame individually.

```
from skimage import io

im1 = io.imread('movie.tif')


print("The mean of the TIFF stack is:")
print(im1.mean())
```

How can I get the mean pixel intensities for each frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the matrix and obtain the mean for each frame like below

```py
from skimage import io

im1 = io.imread('movie.tif')
for i in range(im1.shape[0]):
    print(im1[i,:,:].mean())
```

To plot it you can use a library like `matplotlib`

```py
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im1 = io.imread('movie.tif')
y = []
for i in range(im1.shape[0]):
    y.append(im1[i,:,:].mean())

x = [*range(0, im1.shape[0], 1)]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```